# override error message (The value 'xxx' is not valid for Age) when input incorrect data type for input field asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've tried to override error message when input incorrect data type in input field on HTML form.
For example I have the model like this.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

For view, I put text input for Age to get it value.

When type some string in Age text box like 'test' and press submit button. 
I got this error message

The value 'xxx' is not valid for Age

However, I want to change this message and try many way. There 's nothing effect this message value.

Please could you help me to solve this problem.

Comment: For future reference, if you want to get responses to your questions in the future, you might want to consider marking your questions as answered.

Comment: Thank for your comment, I've review my question and check if it is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DataAnnotations to override the default error messages in MVC, as well as provide your own validation for whatever fields you need to.  See the following:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs

If you are using EF, you will need to create a MetaData class off the EF generated class and then add the data annotations.  The end of the 2nd article covers how to write these classes for entity framework.

In your specific case you will want to do something like:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Person
{
   public string FirstName {get;set;}

   [Range(0, 110, ErrorMessage = "<your error message>")]
   public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

**UPDATE** I did forget one thing that is easy to overlook, you need to include the following JS files for the data annotations to be picked up client side without having to do a post:

- MicrosoftAjax.js
- MicrosfotMvcValidation.js

These should be stock in the Scripts folder of your project (if you are using MVC 2), and you need to include them either on your page or in your master page,

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

you will also need to include

`<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>`

on the page in question.

The client side validation will not let you submit the form until all fields meet validation requirements, as Kaspars Ozols points out you will still need to call Model.IsValid on your controller.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Scott Lance. However, it quite doesn't solve my problem since error occurs in type converter I think.

Comment: Is your view strongly typed?  If the view is strongly typed, then the validation enforces that a value of type int is entered, otherwise you will receive the error message.

Comment: Yes, it is strongly type view model. I just want to override the error message when binder cannot covert value to int. For example,
I fill value 'test' for Age text box. After posting form, there should be error message "Please input number only." not The The value 'test' is not valid for Age.

Comment: If you are not using a strongly typed view for whatever reason you can see if the Html.ValidationMessage helper works for you.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.aspx

Comment: Right, the data annotation should take care of that if the value in the input cannot be coerced to the type of the field (in this case int).  So if your if everything is hooked up right, you should see the error message that you put in your data annotation when you type 'test' in the age box.

Comment: there is also a "Numeric" data annotation

Comment: If you want the 'easy' way out you can always do the following in your view: <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Age) %> <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Age, "Please input number only")%>

Comment: Thank you very much Scott Lance. This solves my problem with simple way. :)

Comment: The last paragraph is just wrong! Model.IsValid still needs to be called as I can pass bad data by tailoring correct HTTP POST request.

Comment: @Kaspars Ozols - You are correct, if you are trying to forge a POST then it will bypass the validation.  I've updated my answer to reflect that you should still call Model.IsValid to be safe

Answer (score 29):

After spending a couple of hours looking around, I see no one really has a suitable answer to this. I have found a solution that works for me so I thought I'd post it.

The problem for me was validating a nullable int. When a non valid value was entered by the user, the default message "The value 'dsfd' is not valid for Issue'.

The solution I came up with was to remove the errors from the model state and add my own.

The classes to perform the validation are below:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ValidInteger : ValidationAttribute
{
     protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
     {
         if (value == null || value.ToString().Length == 0)
         {
             return ValidationResult.Success;
         }
         int i;

         return !int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out i) ? new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage) : ValidationResult.Success;
     }

}

 public class ValidIntegerValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<ValidInteger>
 {
     public ValidIntegerValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, ValidInteger attribute)
         : base(metadata, context, attribute)
     {
         if(!attribute.IsValid(context.HttpContext.Request.Form[attribute.ObjectId]))
         {
             var propertyName = metadata.PropertyName;
             context.Controller.ViewData.ModelState[propertyName].Errors.Clear();
             context.Controller.ViewData.ModelState[propertyName].Errors.Add(attribute.ErrorMessage);
         }
     }
 }
```

Don't forget you'll also need to register the adapter in the global Application_Start()

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(ValidInteger), typeof(ValidIntegerValidator));
```

And decorate your property with the new attribute

```
[ValidInteger(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid number for issue")]
```

Comment: I needed to change [attribute.ObjectId] to [metadata.PropertyName] for this to work, as @Christna also said.

Comment: Helpful answer, but it doesn't work out of the box when your `Request.Form` is filled with a collection of items. For instance: `MyObj[0].MyProp`, `MyObj[1].MyProp`, etc. because the `metadata.PropertyName` will be `MyProp`. So how can I find the full key?

Answer (score 10):

The response from wechel dated February 27, 12 worked for me, except that I needed to replace the line

```
    if(!attribute.IsValid(context.HttpContext.Request.Form[attribute.ObjectId]))
```

with

```
    if (!attribute.IsValid(context.HttpContext.Request.Form[metadata.PropertyName]))
```

I am guessing that the change is needed because I am using MVC4 and the code snippet provided was written in an earlier version of MVC?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to show the Range attribute error message so I used the answer from [wechel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1235376/wechel) and [Christna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2479270/christna) and changed it so the RangeAttribute is used. After adding the Validator class, only a custom Validator needs to be created and registered in the global.asax as shown in [wechel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1235376/wechel)'s answer.

You also need to add a validation message with name "FieldRangeValidation" to your resource bundle. In my project it contains the following text: "Value must be between {0} and {1}"

```
public class ValidIntegerRangeValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<RangeAttribute>
{
    public ValidIntegerRangeValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, RangeAttribute attribute)
        : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
        try
        {
            if (attribute.IsValid(context.HttpContext.Request.Form[metadata.PropertyName]))
            {
                return;
            }                
        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {
        }

        var propertyName = metadata.PropertyName;
        context.Controller.ViewData.ModelState[propertyName].Errors.Clear();
        context.Controller.ViewData.ModelState[propertyName].Errors.Add(string.Format(Resources.Resources.FieldRangeValidation, attribute.Minimum, attribute.Maximum));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (ModelState["Age"].Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            ModelState["Age"].Errors.Clear();
            ModelState["Age"].Errors.Add("<your error message>");
        }
```

Comment: What if I have other types of validation error messages for the Age field. Your method wouldn't work because you are clearing other possible error messages