# Localization message "The value 'aaa' is not valid for ..."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I localize ASP.NET MVC message "The value 'aaa' is not valid for ..." where user fills input for number (int in model view) with string?
In our app we're using custom localizations in database, so I'll like to avoid to use restx files.

Comment: You need to override the `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`, here's an example of doing so: http://blog.dotsmart.net/2011/03/28/generating-better-default-displaynames-from-models-in-asp-net-mvc-using-modelmetadataprovider/

Comment: Thank you for reply. Actually I tried this approach, but it didn't work, this message comes from somewhere in core of asp.net mvc and this message hasn't attribute, so I can't overwrite message... :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [override error message (The value 'xxx' is not valid for Age) when input incorrect data type for input field asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556504/override-error-message-the-value-xxx-is-not-valid-for-age-when-input-incorre)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by creating your own Validation Attributes by inheriting from the [ValidationAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class and overriding the IsValid method.

Within this method you should be able to grab your error message from the db.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply, but I tried this approach and long story short - it didn't work, in method IsValid is argument filled by null...