# Why getting exception message as null

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations, modelstate

I have `ASP.Net WebAPI` based application. Below is my DTO.

```
 public class CustomerTO
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Name required")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Name invalid")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="CountryId required")]
    [Range(1,250,ErrorMessage="CountryId invalid")]
    public int Country { get; set; }
}
```

My API Controller.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]CustomerTO model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           //my stuff
        }
        else
        {
              var msg =  ModelState.SelectMany(s => s.Value.Errors).FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage;

            }
        }
```

If user passed any of the required field as `Null`, it returns the right Error message mentioned in the `Data Annotations`  while if I pass `string` for `CountryId`, it enters into `else` condition(`*ModelState.IsValid = false*`)
But the ErrorMessage is empty.

While If I debug & put the below statement in quick watch.

```
 msg = ModelState.SelectMany(s => s.Value.Errors).FirstOrDefault().Exception.Message;
```

It returns - `Could not convert string to integer: en. Path 'Country', line 6, position 14.`

Why in this scenario, I am not getting the Error message as `CountryId Invalid`

How do I get this?

Comment: I would have thought its because the string Country you've entered is trying to bind to an integer Country. If you put a break point on "ModelState.Isvalid" and inspect the contents of "model"... can you see the same exception in the model?

Comment: @Wheels73, Yes did the same

Comment: I believe the range validators dont cater for string entry, i.e. they only fire if it's a valid integer. It doesn't enforce the type passed in. Try changing your annotation to a regex.  [RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)")]

Comment: @Wheels73, makes sense.I will check Thank you :)

Comment: I'll post as an answer if it works! :)

Comment: @Wheels73, please post right away.

Comment: all done.. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [RegularExpressionAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) does not prevent [RangeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) from throwing an "Could not convert string to integer" exception. So just filter the right one:

```
var msg = ModelState.SelectMany(s => s.Value.Errors)
                    .FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Exception == null)
                    .ErrorMessage;
```

Comment: Yes. It addressed my requirement without the dirty patch Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is a common problem: [SO question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334350/integer-validation-against-non-required-attributes-in-mvc), [SO question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556504/override-error-message-the-value-xxx-is-not-valid-for-age-when-input-incorre).

According to code, from any validation attribute there is [creating a wrapper](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.WebPages/Validation/Validator.cs), derived from [`RequestFieldValidatorBase`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.WebPages/Validation/RequestFieldValidatorBase.cs). Each wrapper calls `IsValid` method of `ValidationAttribute`. In the method `Validate` of `RequestFieldValidatorBase` passing form value for validation.

So, `RequiredAttribute` does not fails, because form value is not empty and is not `null`, and `RangeAttribute` does not fails, because it has problems converting this value to int.

To achieve your desired behaviour it is recommend to create your own validation attribute or use a `RegularExpressionAttribute`. You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9463644/4114093).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the range validators dont cater for string entry, i.e. they only fire if it's a valid integer. It doesn't enforce the type passed in. 
Try changing your annotation to a regex.

```
[RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "Country code invalid")]
public string Country { get; set; }
```

With reference to this link [Integer validation against non-required attributes in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334350/integer-validation-against-non-required-attributes-in-mvc)

As dirty patch, I modified my property from `int` to `string` & decorated it with Regular Expression.

Comment: @Kgn-web, if you keep the data type as `int` then just modify the error message filtering: `var msg = ModelState.SelectMany(s => s.Value.Errors).FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Exception == null).ErrorMessage;`

Comment: @AndriyTolstoy, Yes. Correct, That's Great. Please post this as ans with short explanation